# How do i properly return solutions when backtracking in python?

Tags: python, backtracking

I recently saw a solution to the N-queen problem but im having a bit of trouble returning the solutions.Id please like suggestions on modifications i could make to the code or ways i could go about getting the solutions instead.

My problem goes beyond the N-queen problem though. I tried another problem as well. However couldnt properly return the solution.

For the N-queen problems this was the solution i saw:

```
def n_queens(n, board=[]):
    if n == len(board):
        return 1

    count = 0
    for col in range(n):
        board.append(col)
        if is_valid(board):
            count += n_queens(n, board)
        board.pop()
    return count

def is_valid(board):
    current_queen_row, current_queen_col = len(board) - 1, board[-1]
    # Check if any queens can attack the last queen.
    for row, col in enumerate(board[:-1]):
        diff = abs(current_queen_col - col)
        if diff == 0 or diff == current_queen_row - row:
            return False
    return True

for i in range(9):
    print(n_queens(i))
```

This rightfully get the count of all the solutions for N up to 8. I then try to modify the code to get the solutions but to no avail. The best i can do is as follows(i only change the n_queens function):

```
def n_queens(n, board=[]):
    if n == len(board):
        return board

    count = []
    for col in range(n):
        board.append(col)
        if is_valid(board):
            count.extend(n_queens(n, board))
        board.pop()
    return count

print(n_queens(4))
```

And this outputs:

`[1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1]`

You'll notice i can group the the output in groups of N and get all the solutions. However i want the function to output the solution in groups ie:

`[[1, 3, 0, 2], [2, 0, 3, 1]]` instead

To further elaborate i tried solving this problem :

Given a dictionary of words and a string made up of those words (no spaces), return the original sentence in a list. If there is more than one possible reconstruction, return any of them. If there is no possible reconstruction, then return null.
For example, given the set of words 'quick', 'brown', 'the', 'fox', and the string "thequickbrownfox", you should return ['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'].
Given the set of words 'bed', 'bath', 'bedbath', 'and', 'beyond', and the string "bedbathandbeyond", return either ['bed', 'bath', 'and', 'beyond] or ['bedbath', 'and', 'beyond'].

However i wanted to return all possible solutions eg both solutions to the last example and heres what i managed:

```
def back_track(string,set):
  
    if len(string) == 0:
        return []

    words = []

    for i in range(len(string)+1):
        if string[:i] in set:
            words.append(string[:i])
            words.extend(back_track(string[i:],set))
    
    return words

print(back_track(set = {"bed", "bath", "bedbath", "and", "beyond"}, string = "bedbathandbeyond"))
```

Output:

`['bed', 'bath', 'and', 'beyond', 'bedbath', 'and', 'beyond']`

As you'll see again i get the solutions-ish but i want the function to return

`[['bed', 'bath', 'and', 'beyond'], ['bedbath', 'and', 'beyond']]` instead and i dont have an N to group them by this time.

I also tried doing the following:

```
def back_track(string,set):
  
    if len(string) == 0:
        return " "

    words = []

    for i in range(len(string)+1):
        if string[:i] in set:
            words.append(string[:i])
            words.extend(back_track(string[i:],set))
    
    return words

print(back_track(set = {"bed", "bath", "bedbath", "and", "beyond"}, string = "bedbathandbeyond"))
```

Output:

['bed', 'bath', 'and', 'beyond', ' ', 'bedbath', 'and', 'beyond', ' '].

I can then iterate and find those spaces and group accordingly . However as i priorly said id love for the function to just return the solutions.

Id please like suggestions on modifications i could make to the code or ways i could go about getting the solutions instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem (and btw, don't name your set `set`, thus overriding a Python builtin):

```
def back_track(string, word_set):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return [[]]

    words = []

    for i in range(len(string) + 1):
        if string[:i] in word_set:
            for subwords in back_track(string[i:], word_set):
                words.append([string[:i]] + subwords)

    return words


print(back_track(word_set={"bed", "bath", "bedbath", "and", "beyond"}, string="bedbathandbeyond"))

# [['bed', 'bath', 'and', 'beyond'], ['bedbath', 'and', 'beyond']]
```